# BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Models\User::getFirstMedia()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I am trying to do:

`$this->assertFileExists($user->getFirstMedia()->getPath());` In my test. But when I run it I get this error:

`BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Models\User::getFirstMedia()`.

I do:

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
```

And I also do:

```
class AssortmentTest extends TestCase implements hasMedia
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    use InteractsWithMedia;
```

As far as I know I am using the right traits. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

My test:

```
public function testUserCanUploadFile()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $user = $this->signIn();

        Storage::fake('public'); //Mock a disk
        $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('test.jpg'); //Upload a fake image.

        $assortmentAttributes = Assortment::factory()->raw(); // Use the assortment factory.
        $assortmentAttributes['image_path'] = $file; // Add a additional field in the assortment factory.

        $this->post(route('assortments.store'), $assortmentAttributes)->assertRedirect(); // Post the fields to the assortmentcontroller store method.
        //Storage::disk('public')->assertExists($file->hashName()); // Check if the field exists.

        $this->assertFileExists($user->getFirstMedia()->getPath());
    }
```

My store method controller code:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image'); //request the file
            $fileName = md5_file($image . microtime()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //use md5 for security reasons and get the extension.
            $image->storeAs('', $fileName, 'public'); //store the file in the public folder disk.
        } 
        
         if ($request->wantsJson()) {
             return response([], 204);
        }
```

Comment: Should it not be `implements HasMedia` rather than `implements hasMedia`?

Comment: No I tried that already.

Comment: "_As far as I know I am using the right traits_" Can we see them? What's your `User` model look like?

Comment: @Parsa_237 According to the [docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v7/basic-usage/preparing-your-model) it's `implements HasMedia`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implementing your traits in a `TestCase`, that is not correct. If you are accessing your users media, you should implement the traits on the `User.php` model class, its either located in `app/User.php` or `app/Models/User.php`.

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia {
   use InteractsWithMedia;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I put the code in my `User` model. It did work but it returns the following error: `Error: Call to a member function getPath() on null`. I believe this has nothing to do with the package?

Comment: You need to show more code or stacktrace to let us see whats wrong?

Comment: Of course, please check the edit in my question.

Comment: Probably your controller code that does not work and does not attach the media. After you call your controller it is good to do response->assertOk(); to secure the controller call hasnt failed